# Android, httpPOST generates GET response

Tags: android, http

I have written the following function in order to perform an http POST request:

```
private void httpPost(final File xmlFile){
    String textviewresponse;
    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myURL");
            StringEntity entity;
            HttpResponse httpresponse;

            try {
                entity = new StringEntity(xmlFile.toString());
                entity.setContentType("text/xml");
                Log.d("TAG",httppost.getURI().toString());
                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                try {

                    httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    textviewresponse=EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity()); 
                    Log.d("TAG",textviewresponse);


                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();    
                }finally {
                    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start(); 
}
```

The problem is that when I send the request, I keep getting the response for the GET method, rather than what I should be getting for a POST.

What might be causing this problem?

Comment: Your code seems correct, check your server side response.

Comment: The thing is I've tried to perform the POST request to this server in Java and Python and I get the correct response... It's only when I try and implement it in my app that it doesn't work.