# Server cannot get binary data from Android app when using HttpPost

Tags: java, android, c++, cgi

I use the following code to send binary data to CGI C++ program from Android app (it is called in doInBackground within AsyncTask):

```
public static HttpResponse makeRequestPost(String uri, MyObject obj) {
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dataStream = new DataOutputStream(stream);
        obj.writeRawObject(dataStream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(byteArray);
        entity.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        entity.setChunked(true);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpPost);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "UnsupportedEncodingException. " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ClientProtocolException. " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException. " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

I tested the same server using CURL with data written to a file using:

```
obj.writeRawObject(dataStream);
```

Also, both byteArray and entity variables in the code above contain correct data before calling execute(httpPost).

For some reason, on the server side

```
 char* lenstr = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
```

returns NULL when I run the app. Data I am trying to send are from a few bytes to 30 kB. It doesn't get them on the server side regardless the size. App can communicate with the server but do not attach a binary data. Is it something I am missing?

Something like this works from CURL:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" -X POST --data-binary @file_with_my_obj.bin <url>
```

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Rather than trying to jump from `curl` directly into an android app, it may help you debug better if you first write a normal Java application and successfully get it talking to your server. Once that is working, debugging on Android will be much easier.

Comment: It was a good idea to check it out as normal Java application. Strangely the problem was with 

    entity.setChunked(true);

Without that line it is working fine. I do not quite understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using binary/octet-stream instead of application/octet-stream in setContentType ?

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference. Tried already both. Wouldn't ask a question if I didn't try a long list of rather silly things like this.

Comment: I am afraid that I entered similar problem to that one: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059240/android-httppost-generates-get-response?rq=1